# Can't launch Qt Quick Controls application

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick, qtdeclarative

I downloaded Qt 5.4 and created Qt Quick application with Qt Quick Controls 1.3.

I didn't change anything in code, just built it (as release). Then I copied .exe to another folder, added all the `.dll` files I needed and when I launched my program there was no window, just the program process running in the Task manager.

However, I can launch program which uses QtQuick 1.1.

How can I fix it?

Thanks.

Here is an image for some more explanation:

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deploy Qt5 QML application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25049116/deploy-qt5-qml-application)

Comment: As stated by others you are missing the platform plugin files. Just follow [this guide](http://wiki.qt.io/Deploy_an_Application_on_Windows).

Answer (score 1):

Try to deploy your application using [The Windows Deployment Tool](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html#the-windows-deployment-tool) which copies all DLL and other files necessary for deployment alongside your application executable automatically.

The Windows Deployment Tool could be found in `QTDIR/bin/windeployqt.exe`

Open your command prompt and add the path to your Qt directory and it's `bin` folder to the `PATH` variable like :

```
set PATH= path\to\Qt\bin
```

Next run the windows deployment tool with your application path as the argument:

```
windeployqt.exe  <path-to-app-binary>
```

This way you make sure that the deployed application would work on any computer and you have included whatever necessary.

Comment: Thanks for reply. When i try to do this i have an error: 32 bit, release executable [QML]   Unable to locate ICU library icuin53.dll (this file is in folder with program)

Comment: Ok, i made it work, but there is no window appears. Process in Task manager only :(

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are missing the platform plugin. It should be in the folder of the executable, in a `platforms` subfolder. That's why you aren't getting a window - the runtime fails to load the platform support plugin. On windows that should be a `qwindows.dll` file.