# No windows appears on deployed application on Windows

Tags: windows, qt, deployment, qml, qtquick2

I have developed an QML application (Mingw). I want to deploy this app to other Windows system. My instructions are:

- Building app in Release mode
- Run `windeployqt.exe` for necessery dlls and folders.
- Adding missing dll.

Problem is, when I start my app, it seems to work in background and no window appears. I have wasted a lot of time on this.

Comment: You are still missing some dlls/files. That's a common issue. Have a look to  [this wiki](https://wiki.qt.io/Deploy_an_Application_on_Windows).

Comment: As I remember is such situation, copying QTPATH/qml/QtQuick* into application folder helped me. Check if  Qt QML files were copied on destination machine.

Comment: You are missing QML's files. You must deploy <Qt install path>/qml/* to the your app install path, the following will deploy the QML's files: windeployqt --release --qmldir <your Qt install path>/qml yourApp.exe

Comment: ı am using dependency Walker.This shows me a lot of dll missing like : API-MS-WIN-APPMODEL-RUNTIME-L1-1-0.dll etc....

Comment: Ok! And you must install MS Visual C++ Redistributable Package on your target machine also. Check your Qt version. [here download](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/search/DownloadsDrillInResults.aspx?q=The+Microsoft+Visual+C%2b%2b+Redistributable+Package+&cateorder=2_5_1&site=)

Comment: @devopia, he compiled with mingw, that should be not needed. @ OP, look at the dependencies listed  [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25056475/2538363). They should suffice.

Comment: @BaCaRoZzo Oh! no, they should be needed on target machine.

Comment: @Devopia don't get me wrong. You are right about the dependency. :) Considering that even Notepad depends on `msvcrt.dll`, on recent releases of Win, it's a bit pointless though. That said, here the problem is clearly related to the missing Qt dlls (as also you have pointed out) and it's a common issue with quick applications which can be easily solved following the linked answer.

Comment: I am also build apps in Win 8,

Comment: @AykarKr. API-MS-WIN-APPMODEL-RUNTIME-L1-1-0.dll etc. are false results in Dependency Walker, so you should ignore them. Have you followed the instructions in the Wiki page that BaCaRoZzo gave you? https://wiki.qt.io/Deploy_an_Application_on_Windows

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question. For anyone to get here looking for an anwser, try using:

```
windeployqt.exe . --qmldir <\project\folder\>
```