# How To Deploy Qt MinGW application for windows

Tags: qt, qml, mingw

I have develop an application by using QT/ MinGW 32 bit.This  app work on my pc Windows 8. But ı want to deploy this app to my friends whose computers has windows 7. How to deploy it.Is there a necessary programs,framework to work it like .net framework, C++ runtime etc.. I don't know.I can't find a clear solution

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deploy Qt5 QML application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25049116/deploy-qt5-qml-application)

Answer (score 2):

To *deploy* a Qt app on *Windows*, you'll need to gather files from a few different locations. [Here](http://wiki.qt.io/Deploy_an_Application_on_Windows) is an example how to do it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

See http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html, section "Creating the Application Package". You just have to copy all the necessary DLLs (and other files in case of Qt Quick) to the same directory as executable file. The best way to test whether you have all the required files is to rename your Qt installation directory (C:\Qt) to something else and try to double-click your executable.
Deployment on Windows 7 is no different from Windows 8.